# How to make hard-coded HTML entries saved as if entered in the UI of a CMS?

Tags: php, javascript, language-agnostic, scanf, content-management-system

I doubt I'm using the correct vocabulary (or tags) to explain what I'm looking for, but bear with me:

Eventually part of my page will have a section where things like list items and table data(`<td>`) can be entered/changed by logged in users. Let's say this is one of the `<li>`'s:

```
<!--template-->
<li><a title=""href=""><span></span></a></li>
```

So far my understanding is that if these entries are generated by a UI somewhere (à la Wordpress) these entries need(?) to be written in a database before becoming the generated page. Another thing I'm realizing is that the user of these CMS's doesn't automatically 'get' a copy of the generated page as source code.

What I would like to know is if it would be possible for me to make changes in HTML to this generated record/list inside notepad (I'll likely be messing with some other part of the page) and somehow have the site detect/record any changes as if they were entered through the UI?

- Have PHP code create a file of the generated page
- Have that page scanned for certain patterns/templates
- Add the values found within the template to the DB, repeat

What language/approach could scan text and make database entries from its findings like how I'm describing? I just discovered `sscanf()`, but have no idea how to use it yet. I realize it's stupid to not just use the CMS, but the self-referential and text-scanning quality of it also interests me.

Comment: Is this for caching?  I am really not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.  If you want to use wordpress, it offers both a visual and an html editor, templating and as much control as you want.  There are also plugins to generate static pages and take care of all your caching needs.  These plugins offer ways of clearing the cache as well.

Comment: do you know the names of the plug-ins that generate static pages?

Comment: There is a lot of them. Two of the major ones are W3 Total Cache or WP Super Cache.  There are lots more just search for wordpress caching plugins.

Comment: yeah if i get those working it would meet part of my goals. it's not for caching, but that is something i should be learning about.

Comment: It seems to me that this question was written because: a) you had a problem, so b) you came up with a solution, then c) realised it was an incredibly difficult solution to implement. May I recommend that you go back to step a), post a question directly on the problem you are having, and leverage the creativity of the stack overflow community in solving the problem rather than hacking a CMS?

Comment: That's not a very constructive comment. Forget the cms, I only used it to illustrate my goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you can implement a jQuery "Edit in Place" plug-in with a php script handler. I did something exactly this and their plug-in does all the heavy lifting, all you have to do is feed out the raw HTML with various clues about the table structure.

[See this SO q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708801/whats-the-best-edit-in-place-plugin-for-jquery)... I used it to generate pages that displayed orders. Via editing in place, I made the orders (click-to-edit)-able. In the code, put everything in a foreach loop, then the jQuery links elements to the database through attributes like `<tr id="<? echo $database_ID ?>">` to tie a row to a record and each `<td>` might have the database's column name as ID or a class name.

Comment: I'll probably end up accepting this because it sounds like this approach might be easier to implement than a script that scans the actual .php file.

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface this answer by saying it's almost certainly a bad idea, only tangentially relates to PHP, and creates at least as many problems as it solves. In particular, the security loopholes are terrible. But recently I saw an HTML form on a government website that reinvigorated my sense of humour about "lateral thinking", so just call me Pandora.

Theoretically you could implement something like this with a bit of Javascript and a cross-domain <form> post. In a nutshell, you would:

1. Create an HTML template with all of the tables, lists and other structures you require, plus a <form> containing a hidden input and a submit button. This template would be populated with data by the server application when the user initially requests a particular record.
2. Create a script for the template that parses the tables and lists for values (say, with DOM methods), serializes them (eg, into a JSON string), and sets the value of the form's hidden input to the serialized data.
3. Set the form's `action` attribute to a PHP script designed to deserialize the form data and persist it to a database. Also assign an event handler on the submit button that executes the serializer script before the form is posted.

Now, the trick here is in the user sequence. The user requests some record, which the server returns in a populated template. Ordinarily, a user would work with whatever CMS-style fields the template provides, but [expiredninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487113/expiredninja) instead saves the HTML source of the page, makes changes to the designated tables and lists, opens the modified HTML file in a browser, and clicks submit. The script serializes the data and the client posts the form to the server, which deserializes and saves the data.